# Running and debugging a script and function in R

Tags: debugging, r

I am a newbie. I've an R file ,containing a function with a parameter.
I' d like to perform the two following distinct operations:

1. Run the function
2. Execute step by step and debug it

suppose to have a simple function in an R file

```
"exampleSum"<-
function(x,y){
 x<-x+1
 return(x+y)
}
```

Could you tell me which are R commands to perform what I asked.

Comment: Don't forget to read the help pages of `?debug` and `?browser` very carefully.

Answer (score 30):

You have to call `debug(<functionName>)` to step through a function. The next time you call the function, the so-called browser environment will automatically be opened and list the content of your function. You perform one step by pressing Return or with the `n` command (next). A single step is one block (usually a single line) that will be listed before it's run. To run the function to its end, press `c` (continue). When you're in browser mode, you can use `ls()`, `str()`, `class()`, ... to inspect the objects. Your example looks like this:

```
> exampleSum <- function(x, y) {
+   x <- x+1
+   return(x+y)
+ }

> debug(exampleSum)             # set debug flag
> exampleSum(1, 2)              # run function in browser mode
debugging in: exampleSum(1, 2)
debug: {
    x <- x + 1
    return(x + y)
}
Browse[2]> n                    # next step
debug: x <- x + 1
Browse[2]> ls()                 # show objects
[1] "x" "y"
Browse[2]> x                    # show x
[1] 1
Browse[2]> c                    # run function to end
exiting from: exampleSum(1, 2)
[1] 4

> undebug(exampleSum)           # remove debug flag
```

The last call to `undebug(<functionName>)` removes the debug flag from the function such that it will be run normally the next time it's called.

Comment: `debugonce` is also helpfull when you need only one-time check.

Comment: what if you want to run the next 100 lines?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to load the function into R's workspace (by copy/pasting it to R). Then, you can run it using `exampleSum(x = 1, y = 1)`. You can check that it's there by typing `exampleSum` into R console. You can also run the script file using `source()`. Example of usage would be `source("d:/R/my_script.R")`.

I think you would benefit immensely by reading at least [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html). There is also a plethora of books available to R beginners that explain the very basics. Equivalent information is available in the aforementioned AI2R and free materials floating around the internet. Searching the [R help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-help-f789696.html) list is also... helpful.